# How to get back system apps?

Tags: backup, system-error, system-apps

Recently i ran into a problem, i have linked all my apps including the system apps to the External partition using the link2sd app. unconsciously, i have taken the memory card and formatted the whole partition. After re- inserting i found this issue and later recognised what was the cause for this.

I have tried Factory and Hard Reset but it was being hung when the logo [Panasonic] has appeared. later i have tried installing the same apps which were in dead, but the result is negative.

[image]
[image]

can you please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I was unable to move the system apps back to the internal storage.
Re-installing the ROM did the job as it re-installs the apps back in the right path/location.

Comment: Hi Jordy, thanks for your reply. But, i tried the Hard Reset, it was not going good. Its been hanged in the Logo.

Comment: @user3324135 a reset will not do it. You need to actually flash a new (or the original) ROM to the device. All a reset does is clear out the user data.